Releasing a new version of a real-life frontend SaaS
In React and Vite SPA, we build and bundle our app, create an nginx Docker image with the files, and deploy it to a cloud provider.
The folder structure is something like:
/index.html
/assets
 - index-[hash1].js
 - thing-[hash2].js
 - wow-[hash3].css

Users will then browse to our website and that'll fetch index.html, and in turn will instruct the browser to download index-[hash1].js file.
Lets say that at this point we release a new version of our app.
The files on disk will now be:
/index.html
/assets
 - index-[hash4].js
 - thing-[hash5].js
 - wow-[hash6].css

The users that have our app still open in their browser now navigate to a page that needs to download thing-[hash2].js. However, that file doesn't exist on the server anymore. They get 404 and the app crashes.
I just wonder how a real life frontend app (with hundreds, thousands of users) handle the release of new versions like this, and how should we do that.
So today we do the simple method of creating a new docker image and replace the container.
